# Rebinding a variable not working inside a for loop

Tags: scope, rust

I'm trying to write a loop that iterates a number of times, which also updates a variable in Rust.

```
fn get_next(input: &[u8]) -> (u8, &[u8]) {
    (input[0], &input[1..])
}

fn main() {
    let slice: &[u8] = &vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    for _ in 0..4 {
        let (mynum, slice) = get_next(slice);
        println!("Here's mynum {} slice {:?}", mynum, slice);
    }
}
```

Code is on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b41e2a4728e88a5789d8671b3efbb782&version=nightly&backtrace=0).

This is the output:

```
Here's mynum 1 slice [2, 3, 4]
Here's mynum 1 slice [2, 3, 4]
Here's mynum 1 slice [2, 3, 4]
Here's mynum 1 slice [2, 3, 4]
```

I would expect the `slice` variable to be changed each time to point to the next sub slice. How can I get the `slice` variable to be updated?

This is a minimum example, if I really were iterating over `u8`'s in a slice, I'd do it differently.

Comment: Pedantically, "rebinding a variable" is working *just fine*. You are binding the names `mynum` and `slice` to brand new values. ^_^

Comment: Aka: there is a difference between *binding* (giving a value a name) and *assigning* (overwriting a value by another). The `let` syntax is for *binding*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're defining a new variable that shadows the outer one. Perhaps:

```
let mut slice: &[u8] = &vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
for _ in 0..4 {
    let (mynum, slice_) = get_next(slice);
    slice = slice_;
    println!("Here's mynum {} slice {:?}", mynum, slice);
}
```

Comment: Since all three of us are basically the same, and you came first, I'll just quietly retract my own answer.  :P